# How can I post content to an app users page, linking to their website, from an app running on my website?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am creating an app for a client that allows their clients to schedule posts and post to facebook from the app.

Clients log into my-domain and the app requests permissions to post to their pages. I am fine with getting a list of pages from facebook and requesting the `pages_read_engagement` and `pages_manage_posts` permissions.

My app needs to allow users to select an image (hosted on my-domain) and post that with a link that points at their-domain, along with the post content. Here is an example of an api call I am making using the Javascript SDK (from my app at my-domain):

```
FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed', 'POST', {
    message: post.content,
    link: user.website,
    picture: image.url,
    access_token: page_access_token
}, () => {})
```

I get back an error:

```
(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params.
```

I have had a read through the [domain verification docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification) but I don't understand what I need to do next. Do all of my users have to verify their own domain via DNS verification? Is there a way for me to allow users to post to their own pages, linking to their websites, from my app, without them having to do anything technical? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, your users will have to verify their domains, that is the only way you can edit these properties at run-time while making the post.

Comment: @CBroe So if my client is "Joe's Pizza" and they want to post to their page with the link "www.joespizza.com", how do they verify that they own the domain? I can see there is a settig in the facebook business manager but what if they have just a page, not a business?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification/verifying-your-domain#associate-pages: _“You can still add Open Graph tags to your website to indicate ownership. This does not require the use of Business Manager.”_

Comment: unfortunately that part of the page links to another page that doesn't contain any reference to `fb:pages`, and further searching shows that property to be deprecated. I can't see a way to claim site ownership using og tags at all...

Comment: The documentation has a couple of dead links, but it is basically just `fb:pages` as the property name, and the page id as the value. If you need to associate one domain with multiple pages, implement multiple such meta tags, one for each page.

Comment: As for it being deprecated, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification/faq#faq_495170190855788: _“Q: Will the Open Graph markup tag verification method and DNS TXT/HTML File Upload verification methods all coexist for the foreseeable future? A: Yes.”_